# Pick the exact digit match from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the input strings as below

1) ISBN_9781338034424_001_S_r1.mp3

2) 001_Ch001_987373737.mp3

3) This Is test 001 Chap01.mp3

4) Anger_Cha01_001.mp3

and I am using below regex to pick "001" into TrackNumber group

```
(?:(?<TrackNumber>\d{3})|(?<Revision>r\d{1}))(?![a-zA-Z])
```

However the above also picking up the "978", "133", "803" and etc into TrackNumber group (example 1 and 2) .

How do I change the above regex to pick only the "001" into TrackNumber?

-Alan-

Comment: Is your pattern includes always with `_`? Maybe you need to `Split` with that character and take the the third element of it?

Comment: It can have spaces sometime

Comment: `(?:(?<TrackNumber>\d{3})_[A-Z](?<Revision>r\d{1}))(?![a-zA-Z])`

Comment: @AlanB: What do you think is a rule here for matching `001` ? It's appearing at random places in different string.

Comment: @noob it can be at start or in the middle either with space or _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regular expression will match the 3 digit track number in all your examples:

```
(?<=\b|_)(?<TrackNumber>\d{3})(?=\b|_)
```

- `(?<=\b|_)` positive lookbehind, that the previous character is either a word boundary (i.e. a space) or an underscore
- `(?=\b|_)` positive lookahead, that the next character is either a word boundary (i.e. a space) or an underscore

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP8aI3/1)